# Using MBTiles, GeoServer, and OpenMapTiles

Tags: geoserver, mbtiles

I can’t understand what’s the matter:

1. I downloaded the map from https://openmaptiles.com/ in the mbtiles format

[image]

2. Installed GeoServer and extensions

[image]

3. Published layers

[image]

Several layers are displayed, the rest are displayed in white.

[image]

Why can't I get the rest of the layers?

```
Blockquote2019-12-31 11:09:44,274 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[-2.998352410887321E7 : 2.998352410887321E7, -3.002261605686392E7 : 3.002261605686392E7]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    CQLFilter = null
    Crs = PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
    Elevation = []
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage
    FeatureId = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    Filter = null
    Format = image/png
    FormatOptions = {}
    Get = true
    Height = 768
    Interpolations = []
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@4840559c]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Palette = null
    RawKvp = {EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage, FORMAT=image/png, REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:3857, BBOX=-29983524.10887321,-30022616.05686392,29983524.10887321,30022616.05686392, VERSION=1.1.1, STYLES=, WIDTH=767, SERVICE=WMS, HEIGHT=768, TRANSPARENT=true, LAYERS=main_map:housenumber}
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Request = GetMap
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    ScaleMethod = null
    Sld = null
    SldBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    SortBy = null
    SortByArrays = null
    SRS = EPSG:3857
    StartIndex = null
    StyleBody = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=generic]]
    StyleUrl = null
    StyleVersion = null
    Tiled = false
    TilesOrigin = null
    Time = []
    Transparent = true
    ValidateSchema = false
    Version = 1.1.1
    ViewParams = null
    Width = 767
```

Answer (score 1):

Hum... it displays fine for me, using the GeoServer 2.17.x nightly builds, and the associated mbstyles and mbtiles-store community modules. Won't work with earlier versions. Also, if you are using the official openmaptile mbstyle styles (e.g., osm-bright-gl) some adjustments are needed in the style, as it's referring layers and attributes that are not available in the mbtiles package (don't know why, one would expect them to match up...).

[image]

As you can see there are still a few things not working, like multi-script support, but it's being worked on and will end up (hopefully) in the 2.17.0 release in March 2020.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, for the layers to be displayed correctly I need mbstyles and mbtiles-store?

Comment: Yes, along with a nightly build of the 2.17.x series, currently known as "master": https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/master/

Comment: I still don’t understand what I’m doing. nightly build of the 2.17.x series I downloaded and installed. The geoserver started without errors. However, my all layers are still in white background. I think you need to create styles yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn’t work out for me. please tell me, the sequence you had was this: 1. In the geoserver you put all three extensions mbtiles
-geoserver-2.17-SNAPSHOT-mbstyle-plugin.zip
-geoserver-2.17-SNAPSHOT-mbtiles-plugin.zip
-geoserver-2.17-SNAPSHOT-mbtiles-store-plugin.zip
2. Downloaded from https://openmaptiles.com/ mbtiles file and published it
3. Received 16 layers of mbtiles
4. Have they published each of them and received a card?

Or, in addition, you applied styles by writing manually.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/geosolutions-it/openmaptiles